# No sum() with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm looking for a solution to create sums of +- 10 scores and targets of a product over 6 different dimensions. There are some more i won't bother you with. Of every dimension I need a total. For example

SalesPeriod. Product: Bikes. Dimensions: bmx, size, colours, with bars etc. Targets: 1,2,3,4,5. Scores:1,2,3,4,5.

So 10 totals for bmx bikes with size x, colour red and bars, and 10 totals for bmx bikes, size x, colour red etc etc.

However, every score needs to be calculated only when none of the underlying values is a null. For example score 1 contains a null then no calculation, but score 2 does not contain a null thus should be calculated.

At this point the calculation is done via a case statement which basically checks the values of within each column/score and only calculates the total when the count of scores is equal to the expected rows.

The calculation requires a lot of cpu and with a larger dataset this is very inefficient and it simply takes too long.

I'm looking for a solution that will be much more effecient. What could be my best option to try?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter (or first group by) the products with `Non Null` values only first by using your same `count` method. I don't think there is any other method.

```
SELECT columnid, SUM(column1)
    FROM table
          GROUP BY columnid 
                  HAVING COUNT(column1)=COUNT(*);
```

Then you can join it on `columnid` with another similar query on another `columnN` as well.

(I'm not sure if understood your problem completely, but you basically want an efficient query with `sum(scores)` and `sum(targets)` only when they are not null? or only when they are both not null? or only scores? or only targets?)

Comment: Thnx for your anwer. To clarify. Each score or target should be evaluated seperately wether it contains a null. If score 1 has a null, then null. If target doesn't have a null then do the calculation etc.